# What is the relation between a group action and its restriction to a normal subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

Let $G$ be a group operating on a set $E$ on the right. Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of G.

Let $E/G$ (resp. $E/H$) denote the quotient set of E under the relation of conjugation w.r.t the operation of G (resp. H).

Then:

1. $G$ operates on the set $E/H$ on the right: $g\mapsto(x.H\mapsto (x.H).g=(x.g).H)$;
2. $G/H$ operates on $E/H$ on the right: $gH\mapsto(x.H\mapsto (x.H).(gH)=(x.g).H)$.

Since the relation of conjugation w.r.t $H$ is finer than that w.r.t $G$, we have a canonical surjection $\phi:E/H\rightarrow E/G$.

Question: For $x\in E$, what can we say about the inverse image $\phi^{-1}(\{x.G\})?$

Comment: Well it's the set of $H$-orbits $(x.g).H$ for $g$ in $G$. I find questions "what can we say about ..." difficult to answer. What sort of answer are you expecting?

Comment: I'm trying to see if $\phi$, on passing to the quotient, defines a bijection of $(E/H)/G$ onto $E/G$.

Comment: Yes it does. each $G$-orbit is a union of $H$-orbits, which all have the same size. They form a system of blocks of imprimitivity in the action of $G$ on that orbit.

Comment: I'd suggest you look at various examples. This might lead to some more precise question.